# Bootstrap popover clipped to extent of containing div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want a popover to be contained within a collapsible div: http://jsfiddle.net/nathan9/qgyS7/. However, the popover seems to be limited to the extent of the div. Is there a way to prevent the clipping?

```
<a href="#toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle" onClick="return false;">Toggle collapse</a>
<div id="toggle" class="collapse" style="background-color: yellow">
    Content of collapsible div. Click for popover: 
    <i class="icon-info-sign" id="info"></i>
</div>
```

...

```
<script>
    $('#info').popover({ html: true, placement: 'left', title: 'Popover', content: "<ul><li>The</li><li>popover</li><li>is</li><li>clipped.</li></ul>" });
</script>
```

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14800781/1478467 ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/qgyS7/8/))

Answer (score 9):

Using timer is always a risky business. I've used a variant of Mike Lucid that listens to the collapsible event, shown and hide.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CdNuX/2/)

The code is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle')
    .on('shown', function(evnt) {
      $(evnt.target).addClass('visible');  
    })
    .on('hide', function(evnt) {
      $(evnt.target).removeClass('visible');  
    })
  ;   
});
```

If you want your collapsable to be visible on load, don't forget to add classes **in** and **visible** to your collapsable **div**.

**Edit**

Starting with Bootstrap 2.3, tooltips and popover have a new `container` option. If you set the container to 'body', your tooltips and popovers will won't be clipped. [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snT9P/1/).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

adding `.collapse.in {overflow:visible}` seems to do the trick

http://jsfiddle.net/ZArX7/

EDIT: Above answer only worked in chrome

Here is a piece of jquery that delays adding the class.

```
     $('#toggle_link').click(function() {
    if($('#toggle').hasClass('in')){
        $('#toggle').removeClass('visible');
    }else{
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#toggle').addClass('visible');
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

This solution works

http://jsfiddle.net/fnP7y/

Comment: Unfortunately, this also has the effect of ruining the accordion effect - i.e., the contents of the collapsed div is immediately shown instead of being revealed gradually as the div expands. Is there another way?

Comment: I've been playing with this for some time now, and Mike's answer seems to be the best bet for now. We have an open issue on github for the popover and tooltips now for being placed on certain elements, and I added your fiddle to the list of bugs with the tooltips and popovers - [git hub issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5687)