# My popups on fullcalendar are being clipped

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm using Bootstrap 2.2 popovers in conjunction with FullCalendar but they are being clipped by the calendar's CSS when they appear near the edges - see the fiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nzxyY/6/

The calendar has several divs containing the content but I suspect this is the main culprit:

```
.fc-view {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Is there a CSS hack I can use to make the popover avoid the overflow:hidden constraints imposed by FullCalendar for its contents? There are benefits to having the popover tied to the internal calendar DOM elements (e.g. scrolling) but it currently has the disadvantage of being clipped. I've tried changing the above rule to overflow:visible but that didn't work.
Appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are others questions that can be solved by the same solution, but the context is too much different each time :

- [Make bootstrap popover overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14633364/1478467)
- [Bootstrap popover clipped to extent of containing div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13261393/1478467)

The definite solution is to upgrade to the last 2.3.0 version, or apply [this diff (github)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/d594d6377a7e9cda399c25a450b0d27df704d939#L0L129) to your jQuery tooltip plugin (because popover inherits tooltip behavior).

Then you can make all popover behave the same (mostly because you are delegating the popover initialization to another framework) :

```js
$.fn.popover.defaults.container = 'body';
```

Check the [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/nzxyY/7/).

---

Or you can use the option popover by popover :

```
$('.popover').popover({
    container: 'body'
});
```

Comment: Great stuff :) I saw those two other posts but failed to get either to work. Your solution does however. Many thanks!

Comment: Just an added note of caution around the accepted answer - once the popover is tied to the body and not directly to the calendar event you have to respond to events that ensure the popover lives, dies and scrolls with the calendar element it is intended to represent. I've managed to cover off all the events (I think) that need handling but can be a little messy to control.

Comment: @MarkH Of course.. I didn't thought of that, but that's the counterpart, since the scrolling is managed via overflows, which was the problem in the first place. Feel free to edit my answer to add your handling code.

Comment: @MarkH I've run into the same issue and this answer fixed it (thanks @Sherbrow) but now I need to handle scrolling too. Can you post some clues about how you dealt with it please?

Comment: Fortunately for me my page/calendar does not scroll so that is not an event I've had to deal with (I only have to handle date changes on the Calendar and when it disappears as a drop-down). I would imagine to handle scrolling you'd need to attach an event handler of some kind and move the popup - the same way those annoying, flickery sidebar menus sometimes follow page scrolls.

Comment: @MarkH OK, thanks. We also got around it by fixing the height of the calendar so it doesn't scroll :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `overflow: hidden` you could use a clearfix. Bootstrap [already includes one](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L12) (as a LESS mixin).

```
/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. The overflow:hidden is in the FullCalendar codebase so not code/style I particularly want to mess with if I can find a way that works around it. User "Sherbrow" has provided an example jsFiddle with such a fix so I will accept that as the answer. Thanks anyway :)